# Am I allowed to translate the reCAPTCHA v3 text containing the links to Privacy Policy and Terms of Service?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-hide-the-recaptcha-badge.-what-is-allowed) if I want to hide the reCAPTCHA v3 badge I have to display some text containing links to Privacy Policy and Terms of Service:

> "This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google [Privacy Policy](https://policies.google.com/privacy) and [Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms) apply."

Am I allowed to translate this text?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this question as well. So far couldn't find anything about it in the docs. I've also looked in the localized recaptcha scripts, but found only the English variants of this message.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it can be translated if you keep the links in the text.

I have been using reCAPTCHA v3 for 7 months with translated text on a website with an average of 150 daily validation requests.

It would be nice if Google mentioned this in the docs.

Comment: Agreed. I am about to implement this on a worldwide enterprise platform supporting 10 languages accross 6 websites. We are about to translate it ourself and serve it to millions of users. Hoping google doesn't mind.

Comment: @Charaf so how dit it go?